# How to get a certain region of canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a complete canvas and I want to crop some area of canvas using pure JavaScript/jQuery.

This is something I want (crop some part of canvas):

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Without seeing any code or any attempt to solve the problem yourself, its hard for us to help you.

Comment: You can understand by seeing image...Please with some code

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service !

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.clip()` would help you. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip)

```
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d")
ctx.rect(x1,y1,x2-x1,y2-y1)
ctx.clip()
// draw something you want.
```

If you want to rectangle crop after drawing, `ctx.drawImage` would help you. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)